# How to get the total of a dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

How can I sum the total of a `dataset` and return the answer to a label on another page?

Business layer:

```
 public DataTable CreatePackingStats(DataSet dset)
        {
            using (DataManager dmgr = new DataManager())
            {
                DataTable target = dset.Tables[0]; 
                DataTable actual = dset.Tables[1]; 

                DataColumn[] cols = new DataColumn[1];
                cols[0] = actual.Columns["Hour"];
                actual.PrimaryKey = cols;

                DataTable final = new DataTable(); // This will combine tartget & actual tables

                // Create table columns
                foreach (DataColumn col in target.Columns)
                {
                    final.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(col.ColumnName, col.DataType));
                    if (col.ColumnName.Contains("Target"))
                    {
                        // Add an equivilant actual column
                        string newColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace("Target", "Actual");
                        final.Columns.Add(newColumnName, col.DataType);

                    }
                }
                //// Add rows to new table
                foreach (DataRow row in target.Rows)
                {
                    string key = row["Hour"].ToString();

                    DataRow newRow = final.Rows.Add();
                    // Store column value
                    foreach (DataColumn col in final.Columns)
                    {
                        if (col.ColumnName.Contains("HOUR") || col.ColumnName.Contains("Target"))
                        {
                            newRow[col.ColumnName] = row[col.ColumnName];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Find actual data
                            DataColumn actColumn = actual.Columns[col.ColumnName] as DataColumn;
                            if (actColumn == null)
                            {
                                newRow[col.ColumnName] = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(actual.Rows.Find(key)[col.ColumnName].ToString()))
                                {
                                    newRow[col.ColumnName] = 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    newRow[col.ColumnName] = actual.Rows.Find(key)[col.ColumnName].ToString();
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
                return final;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I would also like to know how you can retrieve this `dataset` and move it to the `aspx` page and display the data in a label set?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use a DataSet vs say Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is really in a database, use SQL to do the calculation for you, instead of reading all the data and doing it yourself.

If the data is only locally in memory, then `IEnumerable<>.Sum()` is probably the best way to do.